# Is there a reasonable lower bound for free energy per site of the 2D Ising model in the presence of an external field?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-statistics, partition-function

Given the standard Ising partition function:
 $$Z(\theta ,h) = \sum\limits_{\bf{x}} {\exp \left\{ {\theta \sum\limits_{(i,j) \in E} {{x_i}{x_j}}  + h\sum\limits_{i \in V} {{x_i}} } \right\}}, $$

is there a closed form expression for the lower bound of the free-energy (Pressure) per-site, defined as,

$$\psi (\theta ,h) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\log \left( {Z(\theta ,h)} \right)}}{n}.$$

My hunch is that is $2\theta + h$ based on taking limits of an approximation suggested in [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-014-1016-9#page-1)

Any ideas on its suitability as a lower bound?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. There are many possible explicit lower bounds on the free energy. What additional properties do you want? For example, a well-known lower bound on the partition function (and thus on $\psi$) is given by the mean-field partition function.

Comment: The original problem I faces looks like this: I need to show that $x =  \psi(\theta, h_1) - \psi(\theta, h_2) + y > 0 $. Since I don't have closed form expressions for $\psi(\theta, h)$, I am resorting to $\psi_{LB}(\theta, h_1) - \psi_{UB}(\theta, h_2)$.  The Tree re-weighted BP upper bound does the trick whereas the MF lower bound is too loose. Hence, I was scouting for 'better lower bounds'. As you can see, if the difference is too large $x$ risks becoming negative. In case you are aware of closed form expressions for good lower bounds for $\psi$ (for a 2D grid) please let me know.